# How to see which modules Firefox sends from web page input boxes?

Tags: firefox

I have a page that contains some input boxes. When I click on the `continue` button in that page, a new page is opened with some information.

How can I see what modules and what data Firefox sends when I click on the `continue` button to generate the next page?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [POST (HTTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)

Answer (score 0):

Press F12, open Network, click the request and inspect the URL parameters, HTTP headers and POST data of the request.